# Laravel make:auth Redirects to Another Route

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, routes

I was trying to create authentication by writing login and register files under the /admin folder. Then I realized that Laravel provides authentication scaffolding with this command:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

I run this command and everything is fine. But when I try to reach the route `auth.login` (created by Laravel), it redirects me to `admin.index` (created by me). What's going on?

**Route**

```
Route::group (['middleware'=>'auth'],function(){
    Route::get('/login', 'HomeController@login');
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@home');
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function home() {
    return view('home');
}

public function login() {
    return view('auth.login');
}
```

Comment: Did You clear Your view, config, route cache clear?

Comment: no did not clear th cache

Comment: Clear it. Your problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

middeleware => auth is trying to validate user login, whenever you hit /login

There is problem in Route, Replace route code

```
Route::group (['middleware'=>'auth'],function(){
    Route::get('/login', 'HomeController@login');
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@home');
});
```

to

```
Route::get('/login', 'HomeController@login');
Route::group (['middleware'=>'auth'],function(){

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@home');
});
```

Comment: i changed it but nothing happened. i tried to use it without middleware and still nothing changed.